# Ruby on rails sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https, openssl

I am trying to make HTTPS API request to Salesforce instance. I am trying to connect from localhost and windows machine.

```
SALESFORCE_URL = "https://my.salesforce.com"
TOKEN_URL = "services/oauth2/token"

request_params =  {
    "grant_type" => "password",
    "client_id" => "3MVG9gOZsF7exF8Pn79zdsxuntzX_0TlVPRKL0R8iPxBQ8dHqh14yzg",
    "client_secret" => "272142298328091392325",
    "redirect_url" => "https://localhost:3000/RestTest/oauth/_callback",
    "username" => "user@xyz.com",
    "password" => "xyz@2018",
}   

url = SALESFORCE_URL + "/" + TOKEN_URL
uri = URI.parse(url)

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
request.body = request_params.to_json

response = http.request(request)

Rails.logger.info response.inspect
```

I am getting below error.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `block in connect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/right_http_connection-1.3.0/lib/net_fix.rb:129:in `request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in request_with_newrelic_trace'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:400:in `disable_all_tracing'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:26:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent/cross_app_tracing.rb:41:in `trace_http_request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:23:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
C:/Users/user/Home/projects/portcullis/mainNew/lib/tasks/salesforce.rake:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not support SSLv3 (POODLE Vulnerability).

Check the suported ciphers using online tools like [Comodo's SSL Analyzer](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/) or [Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html) and configure your HTTP client

```
connection.ssl_version = :TLSv1 or :TLSv1_2
```